# How to convert a SQLite query into a Room query (AndroidStudio)

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-studio, android-room

I have an SQL query which works with "DB Browser for SQLite" and now I wanted to implement this query in my AndroidStudio project using Room.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT column1, tab1.column2, ... FROM

            (SELECT column1, column2, ... FROM table1) AS tab1  

            LEFT JOIN  

            (SELECT column2, ... FROM table1 NATURAL JOIN table2 NATURAL JOIN table3  
                GROUP BY column2) AS tab2  // <<< THIS LINE >>>

            ON tab1.column2 = tab2.column2  

            ORDER BY column1 ASC, tab1.column2 ASC;
```

Now I am getting an error and don't really know why. I marked a line in the code with `<<< THIS LINE >>>"` and in this line there is an `AS` operator. For this `AS` AndroidStudio gives me the following error:

`error: extraneous input 'AS' expecting {<EOF>, ';', K_ALTER, K_ANALYZE, ...`

Can anyone help me to get on the right path? What am I missing here? I thought that the `AS` operator shouldn't be a problem for Room.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had very simple mistake which I didn't notice for a couple of hours. Just in case someone else gets the same error message as me: My error was a closing bracket on the wrong place. So if you also encounter this problem, check your whole query for simple mistakes like a missing bracket or a missing space in front of an operator...